# Multiple inheritance C++ - BaseA access BaseB variable from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have two base classes - BaseA and BaseB and a derived class Derived from BaseA and BaseB.

BaseB defines a variable int **var** (say). Is is possible for BaseA to access variable **var** ??

I tried defining a virtual function in BaseA - virtual int Variable() = 0 and define int Variable() { return var; } in BaseB. But this doesn't work.

Please advise what is the best way to achieve this?

There are many derived classes C with different implementation and I want to avoid defining Set function in every derived class.

Thanks.

Sample code - http://ideone.com/hFjvua

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int Add(int x) { return Get() + x; }
    virtual int Get() = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    int Get() {return a;}
protected:
    int a;
};


class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    void Set(int x) { a = x; }
    //int Get() { return a; }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    c.Set(5);
    std::cout << c.Add(3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) No, `BaseA` will not have access to `var`, unless its `static` or has a `BaseB` pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

If you are overriding methods from `BaseA` in `Derived`, those methods do have access to `BaseB::var`.  If you are not overriding those methods, any method in `BaseA`'s definition would know nothing about `BaseB`.

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual int Get() = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    int a;
};

class C : public virtual A, public virtual B
{
public:
    int Get() { return a; }
};
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/fGt9qu)

Comment: Thanks. Is is possible to achieve http://ideone.com/hFjvua. Reason I am asking -> There are at least 20 classes such as C and I want to avoid defining Get() function everywhere.

Comment: With the code in your attempt, no.  The functions `A::Get` and `B::Get` are not at all related.  You would need to define a virtual method to override in B:  http://ideone.com/gqHteb  That, however, will still require you to override it in your `C`.  My guess is that you really do not need multiple inheritance (as 95% of the time, it is unnecessary) - you should take a closer look at your design to ensure this is really the best path.